# Including $@ to pass on all command line arguments when a shell script invokes itself with bash -c

Tags: bash, shell, arguments, quoting

I need a bash script to invoke itself (actually in a different context, inside Docker container) and I'm using a `bash -c` command to do so. However, I'm struggling with how to pass on all command line variables, even after reading lots of related questions here. This is an example script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# If not in the right context, invoke script in right context and exit
if [ -z ${NESTED+x} ]; then
  NESTED=true bash -c "./test.sh $@"
  exit
fi

echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo "$3"
```

If I save this as test.sh and call it with `./test.sh 1 2 "3 4"` I'd want to see those arguments echo'ed, but only the first one is output.

If I use `set -x` it shows bash inserts some unexpected quoting so the call becomes `NESTED=true bash -c './test2.sh 1' 2 3 4`. That explains the output but I haven't been able to figure out the right way to do this.

Comment: This  https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 should give you some insight.

Comment: I guess I simplified this code too much before asking the question, since I'm actually trying to pass a command to docker exec. It was useful to get an answer from Philippe basically confirming this is not a possible approach, but (given the downvote) should I edit the question to introduce the Docker angle to make it more useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bash -c` should not be used as it cannot handle `"3 4"` easily:

```
#!/bin/bash
# If not in the right context, invoke script in right context and exit
if [ -z ${NESTED+x} ]; then
  NESTED=true ./test.sh "$@"
  exit
fi

echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo "$3"
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately what I'm actually trying to do here is to call docker exec, and I don't know if there is a way around this..

Comment: Docker docs say "COMMAND should be an executable, a chained or a quoted command will not work. Example: docker exec -ti my_container "echo a && echo b" will not work, but docker exec -ti my_container sh -c "echo a && echo b" will."

Comment: If you post your Dockerfile and the command to run container, we may find a solution.

Comment: I eventually accepted that using $@ this way is not possible in Bash, so I added argument parsing above where the script will call itself and passed the expected arguments separately.